# I can't log in in vsftpd with virtual users

Tags: login, ftp, vsftpd, pam

- Ubuntu 10.04 32-bit
- vsftpd 2.3.4 installed from sources

```
# cat vsftpd.conf 
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=NO
anon_mkdir_write_enable=NO
connect_from_port_20=YES
nopriv_user=ftp
chroot_local_user=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/usr/share/empty
ls_recurse_enable=YES
listen_port=1031
log_ftp_protocol=YES
syslog_enable=NO
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
delete_failed_uploads=YES
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_conf
anon_world_readable_only=NO
anon_other_write_enable=NO
no_anon_password=YES
force_dot_files=NO
guest_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd.virtual
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
```

```
# cat /etc/pam.d/vsftpd.virtual 
auth       required     /lib/security/pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/virtual_users.db
account    required     /lib/secutiry/pam_userdb.so db=/etc/vsftpd/virtual_users.db
```

I use db_load to create a simple hashed db with the following command:

```
db4.8_load -T -t hash -f logins /etc/vsftpd/virtual_users.db
```

Well, I can log in with my system user and it enters in FTP folder.
But when I try to enter with a virtual user always it shows: `530 Login incorrect.`

I've tried with [this tutorial](http://www.ubuntututorials.net/installing-vsftpd-using-text-file-for-virtual-users/) that uses `htpasswd` and `libpam-pwdfile` but it also doesn't work.

I've tried see the log files but neither shows anything. I've done several searches with `grep -i vsftpd /var/log/*` and `grep -i pam /var/log/*` but I don't find any clue.

Comment: Please note **vsftpd 2.3.4** is *not* a genuine release. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vsftpd#History

Answer (score 2):

The problem was several:

1. I hadn't installed `libpam0g-dev` before I compiled vsftpd.
2. In the pam file doesn't put the db file extension.

Now it's solved.